# Save objects to array type field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save my array of `car` object to my user.cars field in mongoose.

My User Schema looks like this:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cars: [{
        type: Array,
        required: false
    }]
})
```

I'm saving user cars on cars endpoint like this:

```
router.route('/cars')
  .post(async function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user._id)
      .then((user, err) => {
        if (err) {
           return res.json({err})
        }
        if (user && user._id) {
           user.cars = req.body.cars 
           user.save(function (err) {
             if (err) {
                res.status(500)
                return res.json({
                   success: false,
                   message: err.message || 'Update failed'
                  })
             }
             ioServer.sockets.emit('update-users')
             res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'User updated successfully'
             })
           })
        } else {
          return res.json({message: 'No user', success: false})
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
```

My req.body log looks like:

```
{ cars: [
    {
        type: 'Sedan',
        make: 'BMW',
        model: '525i',
        [...]
    },
    {
        type: 'Coupe',
        make: 'Subaru',
        model: 'BRZ',
        [...]
    },
    {
        type: 'SUV',
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Rav4',
        [...]
    }
    ]
}
```

This code works, but mongoose save data as a new array, so it looks like this:

```
{ user.cars: [
    [
        {car},
        {car},
        ...
    ]
]}
```

But I want to get user.cars as a array of objects instead of passing new array into cars.

Many thanks for help with find where I did a mistake in my code.

Comment: post your full code before `user.cars = req.body.cars `

Comment: I posted full endpoint code @Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model Schema you are defining type of `cars` as `Array`. That's why it is saving data like array structure.

```
cars: [{
        type: Array,
        required: false
    }]
```

Instead create a clear schema of fields:

```
    cars: [{
       type: String,
       make: String,
       model: String,
       ...
    }]
```

This would fix your data.

Comment: :Facepalm: Thanks! Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Robson Wecome!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do not need to find user and save it again instead you can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator to set cars array...

```
router.route('/cars')
  .post(async function (req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$push: { cars: {$each: req.body.cars}}})
      .then((user, err) => {
        if (err) {
           return res.json({err})
        }
        res.status(200).json({
           success: true,
           message: 'User updated successfully'
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
```